# matching different tables in R and working the results

Tags: r

I have one table

```
>treasuremap
     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]    [,4]
[1,] 0.152236 4.2447655 2.991742 37.89973
[2,] 2.354508 0.5854421 1.771338 62.51665
```

and each of the values corresponds to different classes

```
>classes

     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]    1    4    4    4
[2,]    2    5    5    5
```

I want to create a data frame with different columns for each class and each class should have their values added up. How can I do this?

Comment: Please demonstrate what you want as a result.

Answer (score 2):

It is not clear what you want to do.  If this is to group the elements of `treasuremap` by those of `classes` and do the `sum`

```
  tapply(treasuremap, classes, FUN=sum)
  #      1         2         4         5 
  # 0.152236  2.354508 45.136238 64.873430
```

Or, if it is a big dataset

```
 library(data.table)
 dt1 <-  data.table(treasuremap=c(treasuremap),classes=c(classes))
 dt1[,list(treasuremap=sum(treasuremap)), by=classes]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a function that for each classes converts the value to the next row in the class position.

First this function should admit two parameters, the classes values and the treasuremap, then select for each class all the values of treasuremap and dispose them in a vector, and paste them together with a `cbind` and output that as the return of the function. This way you will get the data frame with each row a different class. If you want the sum of these values use `sum`.

Note:To avoid using the for loop use apply family of functions, they will take less.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work?

Create a `data.frame` with both tables as vectors:

`combined<-data.frame("classes"=as.vector(classes),"treasuremap"=as.vector(treasuremap))`.

Then create a table with sums calculated for each class:

`sum_table<-aggregate(treasuremap~classes,combined,sum)`.

That outputs the sums in rows, you if you want them as columns you can transpose the `sum_table` using `t()`.